# Array/Loop does not output primary line

Tags: java, arrays, loops, syntax

I'm having a small problem with my code and I'm not exactly sure how to fix it.. Basically I'm trying to separate the file into different lines (Frames) and then input those lines into the file, and proceed to print them. My first line of the file never prints.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    /*Switch switcherino = new Switch();*/
    Frame frame = new Frame();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to process: ");
    String fileName = input.nextLine();

    FileInputStream inputStream = 
            new FileInputStream(fileName);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader =
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader bufferedReader =
            new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    try{
        String str = " ";

        while((str = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
            String words[] = str.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                words[i] = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(words[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't want to use an ArrayList, as much as it would probably be easier.

Thanks in advance!

File: (switch.txt)

```
fa00 123123123abc 111111222222 data1
fa01 111111222222 123123123abc data2
fa03 444444444444 123123123abc data3
fa01 123123123abc 4353434234ab data4
fa99 a11b22c33d44 444444444444 data5
```

Output: (from System.println(words[i]);)

```
fa01 111111222222 123123123abc data2
fa03 444444444444 123123123abc data3
fa01 123123123abc 4353434234ab data4
fa99 a11b22c33d44 444444444444 data5
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger? Now would be a great time to learn.

Comment: On `words[i] = bufferedReader.readLine();`, you ignore `str = bufferedReader.readLine()`. I don't think you even need `words[i] = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// to count length
int length = 0;
BufferedReader br =
        new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
while(true){
            str = br.readLine();
            if(str == null) break;
            else length++;
} // this loop counts the length!! 
final int clength = length;

//now this is what you want! 
String words[] = new String[clength];
int j= 0;
while(true){
            str = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if(str == null) break;
            words[j++] = str;
            System.out.println(str); //FIXED
}
//Now the words[] have all the lines individually
```

Your code doesn't work because you called `readLine()` twice, which skipped the first line. Try this and let me know.

You don't need to use `split()` since you want the entire line :)

Comment: This works! But now it is outputting words 1 per line, I was hoping to save each line into a words[i] value. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque  i now fixed it. Please check and let me know! If my solution works, upvote and mark it as working. Thanks.

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque I made another fix now for printing spaces exactly. This should work 

Comment: You could just do `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words)); `

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque  you want to save each line in word[i] ?? It means I still need to do something in your code.

Comment: Perfect, sorry I just have one more question.. it seems like the words[i] is just saving each individual word.. Not the line. It just outputs a line. Eventually the point of this code is to save each line into a frame object. I feel like I coded this wrong initially... Is there a way I can get words[0] = fa00 123123123abc 111111222222 data1 ?

Comment: Sure, hold, will fix it for you @TaylorHavart-Labrecque

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque i fixed it now.. Please check.

Comment: The issue is I'm trying to do this without ArrayList, and I don't know the size.. :/ Is there anyway to take the lines and store them into a dynamically allocated array? or even storing each line into a frame object? You've been a lot of help btw, thanks so much.

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque no issues.. Will help you  i will edit the code for your needs.

Comment: @TaylorHavart-Labrecque i completed what you need :) check if it works... And please upvote.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong logic: you read the line, you split it into words so then go ahead and print them - no need to try and read any more lines

```
    while((str = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
        String words[] = str.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
            words[i] = bufferedReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
    }
```

use this instead

```
    while((str = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
        String words[] = str.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                System.out.println(words[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while((str = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
    String words[] = str.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        words[i] = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
}
```

When iterate the file, you split your first line into a String array, 
words[] contains the following elements : fa00, 123123123abc, 111111222222 and data1.
and then **the inner for loop iterate your `bufferReader`** and you assign the lines to a specific index of `word` and then you print out the `word` array elements

**You are not supposed to invoke `bufferedReader.readLine()` in the inner for loop, it breaks your logic.**

Comment: "until reach EOF" - no it doesn't. It iterates the bufferedReader forward for however many space-delimited words are in the current line, e.g. `words.length`

Comment: `words` has 4 elements and there're 4 lines after line `fa00 123123123abc 111111222222 data1, that's why I said EOF:)
`

Comment: I understand why you said it, but if the file had more lines than the shown example, it wouldn't be true